# notify user as push notification when a new record add to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am implementing an intranet web c# application (not mvc) for that whenever new record added to the DB tables like (promotions,birthdays) I need to notify as a push notification to user  on Login to the system.

Since I have very limited knowledge about Signal-R push notification, I appreciate someone's help or advise ..